# Matplotlib using layered histograms

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, distribution

Is there any way to make layered histograms in matplotlib/pyplot?

I have found out how to use transparency with the `alpha` tag but I can't find a way to layer it,

eg. if there is two data sets with a common y axis plot, the smallest frequency should be drawn first so it can be seen layered on top of the larger frequency.

Transparency doesn't work properly as it changes the colour which then makes it mismatch with the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get the effect you're looking for by setting the z-order of the individual bars according to their height:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# two overlapping distributions
x1 = np.random.beta(2, 5, 500)
x2 = np.random.beta(5, 2, 500)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)

# plot the histograms as usual
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
counts1, edges1, bars1 = ax.hist(x1, bins)
counts2, edges2, bars2 = ax.hist(x2, bins)

# plot the histograms as lines as well for clarity
ax.hist(x1, bins, histtype='step', ec='k', ls='solid', lw=3)
ax.hist(x2, bins, histtype='step', ec='k', ls='dashed', lw=3)

# set the z-order of each bar according to its relative height
x2_bigger = counts2 > counts1
for b1, b2, oo in zip(bars1, bars2, x2_bigger):
    if oo:
        # if bar 2 is taller than bar 1, place it behind bar 1
        b2.set_zorder(b1.get_zorder() - 1)
    else:
        # otherwise place it in front
        b2.set_zorder(b1.get_zorder() + 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]